# How can I "multiply" nested lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors, map

Given two nested lists

```
alist={{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}
blist={{r,s,t},{x,y,z}}
```

How can I get

```
res={{a r,b s,c t},{a x,b y,c z},{d r,e s,f t},{d x,e y,f z}}
```

where juxtaposition is the product of those two elements?

I've played around with Outer, Map, etc., etc., but I can't get what I am looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't have given up on `Outer[]` too soon: `Flatten[Outer[Times, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {{r, s, t}, {x, y, z}}, 1], 1]`.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion Maybe I need your persistent exhaustion. I have a train to catch in a few mins but I assume your method works. Thanks.

Comment: try also `Times @@@ Tuples[{alist, blist}]`

Comment: `Inner[Times, alist, #, Plus] & /@ blist // Flatten[#, 1] &`

Comment: @Syed We need to replace the Plus with List - as in Inner[Times, alist, #, List] & /@ blist // Flatten[#, 1] & --- Not sure how to highlight in grey.

Comment: @kglr Very nice and succinct.

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right, I was doing experiments and the wrong one got pasted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Times @@@ Tuples @ {alist, blist}
```

> ```
> {{a r, b s, c t}, {a x, b y, c z}, {d r, e s, f t}, {d x, e y, f z}}
> ```

Comment: I'll accept this answer - as I said above - nice and succinct. Thanks.

Comment: Also very fast, I think

Answer (score 7):

```
Distribute[{alist,blist}, List, List,List, Times]

(* {{a r, b s, c t}, {a x, b y, c z}, {d r, e s, f t}, {d x, e y, f z}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the solution in the comments the following

```
l1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
l2 = {{r, s, t}, {x, y, z}};
Join @@ Table[l1[[i]] l2[[j]], {i, 1, Length@l1}, {j, 1, Length@l2}]
```

also does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Using `TensorProduct`:

```
Join @@ (Transpose@*Diagonal /@ Map[Transpose, TensorProduct[alist, blist], {2}])

(*{{a r, b s, c t}, {a x, b y, c z}, {d r, e s, f t}, {d x, e y, f z}}*)
```

Or using `KroneckerProduct`:

```
Map[Composition[Diagonal, Partition[#, {Last@Dimensions[{alist, blist}]}] &], KroneckerProduct[alist, blist]]

(*{{a r, b s, c t}, {a x, b y, c z}, {d r, e s, f t}, {d x, e y, f z}}*)
```